# Sharing multiple image from SD card to other app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send images from my SD to other app like Gmail or Google drive.
But it is crashing. Could you please help me figure out the problem occurred. Thanks for the help in advance!

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    }

    public void process(View view){
        Intent intent = null; 
        Intent chooser = null; 

        if(view.getId() == R.id.sendImages)
        {

            File pictures = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String[] listOfPictures = pictures.list();
            Uri uri = null;
            ArrayList<Uri> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(String picture: listOfPictures)
            {
                uri = Uri.parse("file://" + pictures.toString() + picture);
                arrayList.add(uri);
            }
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arrayList);
            chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Multiple Images");
            startActivity(chooser);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the Logcat

```
07-02 23:16:02.420 1368-1368/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged received on slotId :0signalStrength=SignalStrength: 22 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=5 cdmdlevel=0 evdolevel=0
07-02 23:16:02.560 227-227/? V/WLAN_PSA: NL MSG, len[048], NL type[0x11] WNI type[0x5050] len[028]
07-02 23:16:04.150 9259-9259/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 17668K/19496K, paused 16ms, total 17ms
07-02 23:16:04.150 9259-9259/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 21.722MB for 2129936-byte allocation
07-02 23:16:04.170 9259-9264/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 9% free 19748K/21580K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 22ms
07-02 23:16:04.250 8836-8836/com.example.hacback17.testimplicitintent D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-02 23:16:04.250 8836-8836/com.example.hacback17.testimplicitintent W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41be5d58)
07-02 23:16:04.260 8836-8836/com.example.hacback17.testimplicitintent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: com.example.hacback17.testimplicitintent, PID: 8836
                                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:289)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                            at com.example.hacback17.testimplicitintent.MainActivity.process(MainActivity.java:79)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
07-02 23:16:04.270 1832-2027/? I/WhetstoneService: Receive am_crash event for pid: 8836
07-02 23:16:04.270 1832-2027/? W/KloServer: Aborted broadcast does not supprt for: com.example.hacback17.testimplicitintent
07-02 23:16:04.270 2305-2763/? I/octvm_klo: klo lock
07-02 23:16:04.280 1005-2055/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.hacback17.testimplicitintent/.MainActivity
07-02 23:16:04.350 2305-2763/? I/octvm_klo: get wanted event[mask:128, name:data_app_crash@1467481564357.txt] from the watchset
07-02 23:16:04.350 2305-2763/? I/octvm_klo: start gathering logcat log...
07-02 23:16:04.500 32225-32225/? D/AutotriggerReceiver: [onReceive]  Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 cmp=com.qualcomm.logkit/.autotrigger.AutotriggerReceiver (has extras) }
07-02 23:16:04.500 32225-32225/? D/AutotriggerReceiver: [onReceive] android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED: data_app_crash
07-02 23:16:04.610 9032-9301/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.UserHandle.isOwner, referenced from method vqb.a
07-02 23:16:04.610 9032-9301/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3134: Landroid/os/UserHandle;.isOwner ()Z
07-02 23:16:04.610 9032-9301/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000c
07-02 23:16:04.680 2305-2763/? I/octvm_klo: gathering logcat log done
07-02 23:16:04.680 2305-2763/? I/octvm_klo: klo unlock
07-02 23:16:04.810 2010-2140/? D/PowerKeeperEventLogManager: notifyForegroundCompomentChanged ComponentInfo{com.miui.home/com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher}
07-02 23:16:04.810 1005-1019/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{43103ee8 u0 com.example.hacback17.testimplicitintent/.MainActivity t491 f}
07-02 23:16:04.820 1005-1019/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:235693712
07-02 23:16:04.840 1005-1103/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:235693731
07-02 23:16:04.840 25183-25258/? I/RenderThread: RenderThread resumed
07-02 23:16:04.840 25183-25258/? D/ScreenElementRoot: resume
07-02 23:16:04.860 1005-1015/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:235693755
07-02 23:16:04.900 1411-1411/? D/wpa_supplicant: RX ctrl_iface - hexdump(len=11): 53 49 47 4e 41 4c 5f 50 4f 4c 4c
07-02 23:16:04.900 1411-1411/? D/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
07-02 23:16:04.900 1411-1411/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: survey data missing!
07-02 23:16:04.910 9032-9301/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1618K, 16% free 14641K/17244K, paused 37ms, total 39ms
07-02 23:16:04.910 9032-9301/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 16.922MB for 196624-byte allocation
07-02 23:16:04.920 25183-25183/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@428f0058 time:235693817
07-02 23:16:04.930 32225-32225/? D/AutotriggerReceiver: [onReceive]  Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 cmp=com.qualcomm.logkit/.autotrigger.AutotriggerReceiver (has extras) }
07-02 23:16:04.930 1005-1018/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:235693828
07-02 23:16:04.980 1368-1368/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged received on slotId :0signalStrength=SignalStrength: 17 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=5 cdmdlevel=0 evdolevel=0
07-02 23:16:05.090 25183-25183/? D/FancyDrawable: doPause:   [miui.maml.FancyDrawable@43952fc0]
07-02 23:16:05.090 25183-25183/? D/MultipleRenderable: setPause: true miui.maml.FancyDrawable@43952fc0
07-02 23:16:05.090 25183-25183/? D/RendererCore: self pause: miui.maml.RendererCore@4397a5e0
07-02 23:16:05.090 25183-25183/? D/ScreenElementRoot: pause
07-02 23:16:05.110 1005-1018/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{42942b20 u0 com.miui.home/.launcher.Launcher t1} time:235694002
07-02 23:16:05.110 1005-1018/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_stopped time:235694004
07-02 23:16:05.120 25183-25183/? D/FancyDrawable: doResume:   [miui.maml.FancyDrawable@43952fc0]
07-02 23:16:05.120 25183-25183/? D/MultipleRenderable: setPause: false miui.maml.FancyDrawable@43952fc0
07-02 23:16:05.120 25183-25183/? D/RendererCore: self resume: miui.maml.RendererCore@4397a5e0
07-02 23:16:05.120 25183-25183/? D/ScreenElementRoot: resume
07-02 23:16:05.150 1005-2066/? I/ActivityManager: Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{43cd8b20 u0 com.miui.cloudservice/.state.MiCloudSyncStateService}
07-02 23:16:05.760 1005-1019/? I/ActivityManager: Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{433bb4f0 u0 com.miui.cloudservice/.sync.AlertSyncService}
07-02 23:16:05.760 1005-1019/? I/ActivityManager: Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{433bb4f0 u0 com.miui.cloudservice/.sync.AlertSyncService}
07-02 23:16:05.780 1005-1019/? I/ActivityManager: Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{433bb4f0 u0 com.miui.cloudservice/.sync.AlertSyncService}
```

Comment: On which line does it crash? What does it say in the LogCat?

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: It crashes when I click the button. I have also provided the Logcat now.